# Is it possible to expand a FlagsProperty by default in a wxPython PropertyGrid?

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

Consider this snippet during the initialization of a wxPython window:

```
pg = wxpg.PropertyGrid(self)
prop = wxpg.FlagsProperty("TestFlags", labels=['A', 'B', 'C'], values=[1, 2, 4])
pg.Append(prop)
```

Is there anything I could do to `pg` or `prop` to force the "TestFlags" property to be expanded when the window is displayed?  Likewise I want the minSize of the PropertyGrid window to account for the expanded property.

A scouring of the wxWidgets and wxPython docs has uncovered no attributes or flags that I could mutate to make this happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay this is actually very easy.  The wxPython docs do not report methods that are inherited.  I found the correct methods to do what I need (Expand() and ExpandAll()) in the documentation for wx.propgrid.PropertyGridInterface